# Trouble with relative URLs in a master page logo between development and live

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a master page which displays a footer with the company logo in it.

The URL is dynamic and pulled from the database as different companies have different logos when they log in.

The code is a simple view with `<img src='@Model.TheUrl'>` in.

The model is populated like:

`model.TheUrl = "/Images/Logos/" + logoName;`

The problem I have is that as you navigate around the site, the logo stops working, e.g. you're on `www.site.com/home` and you go to `www.site.com/home/pages`

I've tried all variations of / before and not before. I suspect the issue is that on my local machine, the URL of my website is `localhost/MySiteName/` but on the staging server it's `www.mydomain.com`. I think this creates a problem. Maybe changing `/Images/Logos...` to `/MySiteName/Images/Logos` would work, but that wouldn't work when it was deployed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UrlHelper to achieve this.

Change your model value to

```
model.TheUrl = "~/Images/Logos/" + logoName;
```

And then use the UrlHelper in the View:

```
<img src='@Url.Content(Model.TheUrl)'>
```

This will create a base-relative url.